# JNI calls interleaved with regular Java calls - what is the execution order?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have been experimenting with JNI recently, in order to port some existing C++ libraries.

As part of my testing I created a simple 'helloworld' program. I am calling a simple native function in C++, that just prints messages. I am a bit curious about some behavior I have observed while executing the program - it seems that all the native function messages/responses gets printed after Java `System.out.print`'s. Is this because native calls are executed after Java calls, or shall I just ignore this behavior?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld app = new HelloWorld();
        System.out.println("say");
        app.print();

        System.out.println("what");
        app.print();
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
say
what
hola, world !
hola, world !
```

The native function is as follows:

```
Java_HelloWorld_print(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    printf("hola, world !\n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Does fflush after print in native code makes a difference?

Comment: you mean fflush(stdout); ?? cuz i tried that and gave same output. Thanks

Comment: oh sorry, i updated wrong native method. Yeah using fflush(stdout) makes the difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this because native calls are executed after Java calls

No, it almost certainly has to do with how the output gets buffered on the C++ and Java sides.

The execution order of the calls is exactly as it appears in your code (Java, C++, Java, C++).